# Updating Azure Sql Database Tags Using Java SDK

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-java-sdk

How do we update Azure SQL Database's tags using Azure's Java SDK? We could do it using withTag() and withoutTag() for Virtual Machines (interface UpdateWithTags). But I can't find corresponding APIs for Databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API which is defined in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/manageddatabases/update) in order to update your SQL database. In the request body, there is Parameter called tags, which you can use it

**PATCH** `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/{managedInstanceName}/databases/{databaseName}?api-version=2017-03-01-preview`